# mongodb dbrefs examples using Java

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I tried to find working examples of **java/SpringData mongodb DBRefs** but couldn't find any. I'm new to Mongodb and looking for ways to use SQL join-like functionality to aggregate/merge data from two mongo collections based on a common id.

Could someone point me in the right direction? Is application-level aggregating/merging is the only best solution with Mongo/Java/Spring combination?

Answer (score 3):

There is a significant difference between DBRefs and Joins.

If you have two collections, that you are trying to join, then it might be worth looking at your data model. It could be the case, that you are using a relational modelling approach. This will not work with MongoDB.

It is usially better, to denormalize the dependent collection into the document of the master collection.

Then you do not need to join at all and make the most of the document model.